# Perform Operations after grouping dataframe by id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My current dataframe:

```
df=
[id,date,       session_rank,sales]
[1, 06-01-2018, 5,             10 ]
[1, 08-01-2018, 6,             30 ]
[2, 06-01-2018, 1,              0 ]
[3, 05-01-2018, 3,             30 ]
```

I am looking to aggregate by `id`, so that I end up with 1 row per `id` in the following way:

```
df_new=
[id,total_days,total_sessions,total_sales]
[1,  3,         2,             40        ]
[2,  1,         1,             0         ]
[3,  1,         3,             30        ]
```

Calculations:

> days=max(date)-min(date) for each id.
> Dates are inclusive, so 08-01-2018 - 06-01-2018 = 3. Also, if only 1 date or session is given for a user, then just fill in 1.
>
> sessions=max(session_rank)-min(session_rank) for each id
>
> sales=sum(sales) for each id

Hope someone can help!

Comment: It is simillar!.......... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57897642/complex-grouping-of-dataframe-with-operations-and-creation-of-new-columns/57898185#57898185

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many ways to do this. M thinking is to groupby date, then perform a custom agg.  Note: I'm reconstructing your df, and using a converter on date to get a datetime dtype.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = '''id  date  session_rank  sales
       1  06-01-2018  5             10 
       1  08-01-2018  6             30 
       2  06-01-2018  1              0 
       3  05-01-2018  3             30'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), sep='\s+', converters={'date': lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d-%m-%Y')})
df = df.groupby('id').agg({'date': lambda x: ((x.max()-x.min()) + '1D').days,
                           'session_rank': lambda x: x if len(x)<2 else x.max()-x.min(),
                           'sales': sum})

print(df)

    date  session_rank  sales
id                           
1      3             1     40
2      1             1      0
3      1             3     30
```

Comment: Kind of.  I don't agree with OP's expected results based on what they're asking.  Id #1 should be session_rank=1 if max=6 and min=5

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.groupby('id').agg({
    'session_rank': lambda x:x if len(x)<2 else x.max()-x.min(),
    'sales': lambda y: y.sum(),
    'date': lambda z: ((z.max()-z.min()) + '1D').days})
```